# RestKit mapping: how to map multiple array objects

Tags: ios, iphone, restkit

I'm trying to mapping but showing error

The representation inputted to the mapper was found to contain nested object representations at the following key paths: **blocks, description, id, name**

This likely indicates that you have misconfigured the key paths for your mappings.,

**keyPath=null, DetailedErrors=(
)}}, keyPath=null, NSLocalizedDescription=No response descriptors match the response loaded.}**

My json response is 
[image]

My code is:

```
@interface PropertyBlock : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* description;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Blocks * blocks;

-----------
@interface Blocks : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* url;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Rooms * rooms;

-----------
@interface Rooms : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Tenants* tenants;

-----------
@interface Tenants : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Payments* payments;

-----------
@interface Payments : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* amount;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* amount_type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* discount;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* receipt_no;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* created_at;

 //Mapping Code

 RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];


    RKObjectMapping *venueMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[PropertyBlock class]];
    [venueMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"id",@"name",@"description"]];


    RKObjectMapping *blockMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Blocks class]];
    [blockMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"id", @"name", @"url"]];
    RKRelationshipMapping *relation = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"blocks" toKeyPath:@"blocks" withMapping:blockMapping];
    [venueMapping addPropertyMapping:relation];



    RKObjectMapping *roomMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Rooms class]];
    [roomMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"id", @"name"]];
    RKRelationshipMapping *roomrelation = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"rooms" toKeyPath:@"rooms" withMapping:roomMapping];
    [blockMapping addPropertyMapping:roomrelation];




    RKObjectMapping *tenantsMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Tenants class]];
    [tenantsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"id", @"name"]];
    RKRelationshipMapping *tenantRelation = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"payments" toKeyPath:@"payments" withMapping:tenantsMapping];
    [roomMapping addPropertyMapping:tenantRelation];



    RKObjectMapping *paymentMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Payments class]];
    [paymentMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"id", @"amount",@"amount_type",@"discount",@"receipt_no",@"created_at"]];
    RKRelationshipMapping *paymentRelation = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"payments" toKeyPath:@"payments" withMapping:tenantsMapping];
    [tenantsMapping addPropertyMapping:paymentRelation];
```

Comment: can you be clear what is the error you are facing

Comment: DetailedErrors=(
)}}, keyPath=null, NSLocalizedDescription=No response descriptors match the response loaded.}

Comment: Then i calling 
[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath this method show above error.

Comment: You haven't shown the descriptor

Comment: RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor =
    [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:venueMapping
                                                 method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                            pathPattern:urlMethodUrl   
                                                keyPath:nil
                                            statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];

Comment: should have added it to the question. presumably the path pattern doesn't match